# How to change order status to holded?

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm using the code below for change order status to holded

```
$order->setState("holded")->setStatus("holded");
$order->save();
```

But after run this code, the status of order is blank, what am i wrong ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems well. But ensure that `holded` is the default status of order state `holded`.

Using `$order->setState("holded")->setStatus("holded");`  means automatically not changes the order status to hold.

before changes an order status to hold, you have to check the order is available for the hold by `canHold()`.

```
if ($order->canHold()) {
    $order->setState("holded")->setStatus("holded");
    $order->save();
}
```

If you want do this at a class then use below

```
 protected $orderManagement;
public  function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
)
{
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
}
public function canChangetoHold()
{

    try {
        $this->orderManagement->hold(10); //10 is order id

    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        // some error
        $e->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //You have not put the order on hold
    }
}
```

Comment: I also found code on the file : vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Hold.php

Comment: YEs, you will get code at there.